# eclipse console differentiate logs from multiple web applications in same server

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, logging

I've two different web applications deployed on a Tomcat server in eclipse (Helios). The logs from the two applications go the same console which makes it clumsy. Is there a way we can split the logs from two applications into separate consoles or otherwise color code it in the same console?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an [ascii console plugin](http://www.mihai-nita.net/eclipse/) which would help to display logs from multiple applications in different color in the same console. There could be other plugins that achieves the same purpose. Basically, the log configuration for each application will mention a ascii color code and on each log statement will be prefixed by the ascii color code. THe plugin identifies the color codes and display the log statement in the specified color